# A old text file with special format

Tags: file-format, hp-ux

I am working on HP-UX project, there are a old document. Can open it with vim, but there are some special character among text. For example:

```
.P
   "xxxxx"
.AL 1 10
.LI  "xxx"
.H 3 "xxxx"
```

It looks like html but not be html.  Is it possible convert it to modern document?

Comment: "Convert it to modern document?" Do you mean something like [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `troff`.  Install GNU troff (Groff) and try:

```
groff -Thtml -pet -mm input.mm > output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess more details are needed - some ideas you may try:

First, issue a `file` command for the file.  It will probably tell you what type of file is.

```
jim@debian:~$ file foo.bar
foo.bar: ASCII text
```

Second, search for similar files and see if there's a program to open them in the machine - maybe, they are binary files for some program out there, and you just don't know which one.

Last, but not least, I believe you are right - looks like HTML code to me, so maybe this is used by an application as a kind-of intermediate language, that is parsed later to transform it to *real* HTML.

I hope this helps!